# C++ количество знаков после зяпятой

Tags: c++, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть:

```
double v = 1.8467....;
```

Надо вивести:

```
cout << 1.8467362 << endl;
```

Помогите пожалуста

> Если неправильно задал вопрос, поправте меня

Comment: Если придираться к тому, как задан вопрос. Не совсем понятно, что же именно у вас есть? Нет такого оператора в с++ - четверо-точие... В любом случае, в качестве намека может подойти ответ на [этот вопрос с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout), там есть примеры кода и ссылки на документацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь соответствующей возможностью из [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip):

```
cout << setprecision(8) << v;
```

Answer (score 0):

> precision может вывести любое количество знаков после запятой,в аргументах указуешь сколько знаков надо

```
    void main()
    {
     double d = 1.84673563645;
     cout.precision(15);
     cout << d << endl;
    }
```